# HiveContext causes a NullPointer on spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, cloudera, hadoop2

I am trying to execute a foreach loop on a DataFrame in a spark task. I submit my spark task with the following cmd.

```
 spark-submit --class Hive_Cis.DataAnalyze --master local --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 1g --name DataAnalyze --conf "spark.app.id=DataAnalyze" Hive_CIS-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Now my class that is the driver for the spark task is as follows.

```
enter public class DataAnalyze {

public static void main(String[] args){

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DataAnalyze").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);
    DataFrame dataSrcsTable = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM  default.data_tables_metrics");

    dataSrcsTable.show();
    dataSrcsTable.foreach(new DataTableReader(hiveContext));
}//END OF MAIN
```

Then the class which extends the AbstractFunction1 is:

```
public class DataTableReader extends AbstractFunction1 implements Serializable{

private HiveContext hiveConnection;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1919222653470174456L;

public DataTableReader(HiveContext hiveData){

    this.hiveConnection = hiveData;
}

@Override
public BoxedUnit apply(Object o) {

    Row row = (Row)o;

    DataFrame examinetable;
    String tableName;
    String query;
    Timestamp lastCurrentDate;

    long count;

    if(!row.isNullAt(0)) {
        tableName = row.getString(0);
        count = row.getLong(1);
        lastCurrentDate = row.getTimestamp(2);

        System.out.println("\n"+ tableName + "\n");

        query = new String("SELECT * from default.");
        query = query + tableName;

        System.out.println("\n"+ query + "\n");

        //TODO this creates a null pointer issue
        //Not serializing correctly maybe ?
        examinetable = hiveConnection.sql(query);

        try {
            if (examinetable == null) {
                System.out.println("\n\n Error input is null \n\n");
            }

            if (count < examinetable.count()) {
                System.out.println("Count is low");
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){

            System.out.println("\n Null pointer at get table \n");
        }

    }


    return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
}
```

}//END OF CLASS

At the TODO point there is a nullpointer issue with the following stack trace.

```
    16/09/01 07:35:38 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf.setConf(SQLConf.scala:588)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.setConf(SQLContext.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:555)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:553)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.parseSql(HiveContext.scala:333)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
at Hive_Cis.DataTableReader.apply(DataTableReader.java:53)
at Hive_Cis.DataTableReader.apply(DataTableReader.java:16)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/01 07:35:38 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf.setConf(SQLConf.scala:588)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.setConf(SQLContext.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:555)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:553)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.parseSql(HiveContext.scala:333)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
at Hive_Cis.DataTableReader.apply(DataTableReader.java:53)
at Hive_Cis.DataTableReader.apply(DataTableReader.java:16)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However I can see that a connection is being made to the hive metastore:

```
16/09/01 07:35:37 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 1.1.0
16/09/01 07:35:37 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.6.0-cdh5.7.2
16/09/01 07:35:37 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.6.0-cdh5.7.2
16/09/01 07:35:38 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://*************:9083
16/09/01 07:35:38 INFO hive.metastore: Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 2
16/09/01 07:35:38 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.